# How can I enforce a key to be of type string (and not number or symbol)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a type for an object with `string` keys and arbitrary values. Thus, my desired type (let's call it `Obj`) should cause a type error for the following `obj` object because its key is of type `number`:

```
const obj: Obj = {
    1: "foo" // I'd expect a TS error here because the key 1 is of type `number` and not `string`
};
```

However, all of my attempts don't cause any TS error! Here are my three attempts:

1. Built-in `Record` type (which implicitly uses the `in` operator):

```
type Obj = Record<'1', any>;

const obj: Obj = {
    1: "foo" // TS error expected! ❌
};
```

2. Mapped type (to recreate `Record` type):

```
type Obj = { [key: string]: any };

const obj: Obj = {
    1: "foo" // TS error expected! ❌
};
```

3. Custom `Record` type with [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type MyRecord<K extends string, T> = {
    [P in K as string]: T;
};
type Obj = MyRecord<string, any>;

const obj: Obj = {
    1: "foo" // TS error expected! ❌
};
```

4. Even using a literal type `'1'` does not enforce the *key* to be `'1'`, but allows the number `1`:

```
type Obj = Record<'1', any>;

const obj: Obj = {
    1: "foo" // TS error expected! ❌
};
```

Is it in general possible, or is it due to some property of a JavaScript object that it's not possible?

[TS Playground of my code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlC8D2AnAJkg3gFBIlIAuAnjMgPIBGAVkgLyrrY4A8A5AIzcAaJCGAUAfAG5CxUpmBQySDIwBcSek1ZFSOpLzUAiAGYYMBpAHoLSACoBlJBCxZsjgB7V4ZCDgCESQBlyGRIAXykQ6VBIWARkAFkQGGocGypkbVJKanVGFgIkAG0AawgKNQUsAEtgAHMAXTURCiQw6R05BSVVHM0CYN19JGNTcytbBycXLHdPbz9A-taIwijoOEQkOIo0TFwAdUqyAAsAaVK0MESYapq+nSz47fZcThP3b2AcKCQKm6EbMR5DK6QoABSQ1SQbxA31+tQatikOla9zSPTyWx2HE4cJqQiakjasgw8kUygYag0QP6OkGwzMlms9kczlcEA86Dm-iCyPCkXAa1ibF2OAOxwAMocnCAADZ2MhVWqpbLA8hoqmsLEvPiCYSiQn9Dpk7oau4gvSGEwMsbMyZsjleHzcxbhIA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1` is coerced to a `string` (`"1"`) when defining an object literal. You cannot define an object with `number` keys:

```js
const obj = {
  prop: 'value',
  1: 'another value',
};

for (const key in obj) {
  console.log(key, typeof key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the [`keyof` page of TypeScript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)

> JavaScript object keys are always coerced to a string, so obj[0] is always the same as obj["0"]

So in fact `{1: "foo"}` is just as same as `{"1": "foo"}`.

Comment: Ok. Interestingly `[key: number]: any` also works for string keys.